# FirebaseError browserErrorMessage: "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: ServiceWorker script evaluation failed"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, push-notification, web-push

I have used FCM as per this `https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client`, and I am getting below error:

```
FirebaseError {code: "messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration", message: "Messaging: We are unable to register the default s…ed (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).", browserErrorMessage: "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: ServiceWorker script evaluation failed", stack: "FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to registe…tp://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:57713:26"}
browserErrorMessage: "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: ServiceWorker script evaluation failed"

code: "messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration"
message: "Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: ServiceWorker script evaluation failed (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration)."
stack: "FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: ServiceWorker script evaluation failed (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).↵    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:57713:26"
__proto__: Error
```

What I am doing:

1. Created a react app by create-react-app pushnotification
2. Downloaded firebase using sudo npm install --save firebase in my project
3. created a firebase.js file in src folder of the react app with below content

   ```
   import firebase from 'firebase';

   var config = {
       apiKey: "MY_KEY",
       authDomain: "MY_Domain",
       databaseURL: "MY_DBurl",
       projectId: "My_ProjectID",
       storageBucket: "My_StorageBucket",
       messagingSenderId: "My_Msg_id"
   };
   firebase.initializeApp(config);

   const messaging = firebase.messaging();

   messaging.requestPermission().then(function(){
       console.log("Have Permission");
   }).catch(function(error){
       console.log(error);
   })
   ```

and when I refresh my web app it asks for the permission like below:

[image]

So far everything is working, now I am updating my firebase.js file like below to send push notification:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase';

var config = {
    apiKey: "MY_KEY",
    authDomain: "MY_Domain",
    databaseURL: "MY_DBurl",
    projectId: "My_ProjectID",
    storageBucket: "My_StorageBucket",
    messagingSenderId: "My_Msg_id"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.requestPermission().then(function(){
    console.log("Have Permission");
    return messaging.getToken();
}).then(function(token){
    console.log(token)
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});

messaging.onMessage(function(payload){
    console.log(payload);
})
```

also I have create a firebase-messaging-sw.js file with below content:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase';

var config = {
    apiKey: "MY_KEY",
    authDomain: "MY_Domain",
    databaseURL: "MY_DBurl",
    projectId: "My_ProjectID",
    storageBucket: "My_StorageBucket",
    messagingSenderId: "My_Msg_id"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

In my public folder and now when I do a page refresh I get above error:

[image]

Comment: @All alos i have looked into similar issue but nothing worked, earlier the same code was working but form last copule of days its not working

Comment: Looks like you are not importing firebase app from static google script lib. Are you sure it is not needed with React? See the answers below. 
**!!! Important !!!** Also with some projects (angular) I had to import `"https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.2/firebase-app-compat.js"` and `"https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.2/firebase-messaging-compact.js" `notice the `"-compact"`

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, doing firebase integrations take days because of their incomplete/unclear docs (at least for me!). Sharing what worked for me.

My setup:

- App: react web app
- Using firebase js [sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js)

**What worked for me:**

1. Directory structure:

```
-src
-public
--firebase-messaging-sw.js
--index.html
```

Yes, had to put firebase-messaging-sw.js inside 'public' instead of root folder. Maybe it has to be at same depth as of the main entry point file (index.html)

2. Added these scripts in index.html: ([reference](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/messaging/index.html))

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    try {
        if (!firebase.apps.length) {
            const firebaseConfig = { //from firebase project setting
            };
            firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        }
    
        const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    
        messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
            console.log('Message received. ', payload);
    
            const notificationTitle = 'OnMessage Title';
            const notificationOptions = {
                body: 'OnMessage body.'
            };
    
            return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
        });
    
        function resetUI() {
            const vapidKey = '<>'; //from firebase project settings
            messaging.getToken({ vapidKey: vapidKey }).then((currentToken) => {
                console.log("currentToken", currentToken);
                if (currentToken) {
                    //..
                } else {
                    console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
                    requestPermission();
                }
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
            });
        }
    
        function requestPermission() {
            console.log('Requesting permission...');
            Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
                if (permission === 'granted') {
                    console.log('Notification permission granted.');
                    resetUI();
                } else {
                    console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.');
                }
            });
        }
    
        resetUI();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("firebase startup error ", e);
    }
</script>
```

Later, I was able to move the above code in script to App.js.

3. firebase-messaging-sw.js: ([reference](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/messaging/firebase-messaging-sw.js))

- Had to put firebase.intializeApp() in both index.html and in this file, otherwise I was getting "firebase serviceworker script evaluation failed".

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.2/firebase-messaging.js');
    
const vapidKey = '<>'; //from firebase project settings
const firebaseConfig = { //from firebase project settings
    ...
};
    
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    try {
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("sw error", e)
    }
}
    
let messaging = firebase.messaging();
    
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
    console.log('firebase Received background message ', JSON.stringify(payload));
    
    // const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
    // const notificationOptions = {
    //     body: 'Background Message body.',
    //     // icon: '../assets/icon.png'
    // };
    
    // return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    //     notificationOptions);
});
```

Comment: can you please share the link of the complete repo?

Comment: if you are asking about my codebase, sorry it's private. If you meant firebase official examples: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging

Comment: thanks man this was super helpful. Such subtle problems with their samples.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should configure Web credentials.

```
messaging.usePublicVapidKey("set your key here")
```

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#configure_web_credentials_in_your_app
- ["Request is missing authentication credential" error when calling firebase.messaging.getToken()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55800561/request-is-missing-authentication-credential-error-when-calling-firebase-messa/55806977#55806977)
- https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging

Comment: hi using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54996206/firebase-cloud-messaging-where-to-find-public-vapid-key i have generataed the key but still issue is same